# Substring search program always results in false

Tags: string, assembly, x86, masm, x86-16

[This gist](https://gist.github.com/hjpotter92/6497303) hosts all required files. I'll first explain what I'm doing here.

## Objective

The program should read two separate strings of various lengths, less than 200, terminated by a newline character. After reading the strings, search if either of the two string is a sub-string of another. In case that both of them are the same; return true.

### Return values

- **`TRUE`**: One of the string IS a sub-string.
- **`FALSE`**: Both strings are entirely different.

## Procedure

What I'm doing in my program is:

1. Read the strings into variables `STR1` and `STR2` by calling the procedure [`READ_STR`](https://gist.github.com/hjpotter92/6497303#file-readstr-asm). The procedure returns the length of strings in BX. I'm storing the length of first string in another variable `L1` of type `DW`.
2. Compare the length of second string (now in `BX`) with `L1`.

   - If both are equal, set `CX` to 1
   - Else set `CX = abs.( BX - L1 )` | Absolute of `BX - L1`.

   This is to set how many times can a smaller string be iterated inside the larger one. Set the `DI` to point to the longer string.
3. Set `L1` to be the length of smaller string.
4. Set `DX` as 0. Start a loop with the value of `CX` as set above.
5. Add `DX` to `DI` and use `CMPSB` to compare the shorter string `SI` with longer one `DI`. Update `CX` to be `L1` so that `REPE CMPSB` can work.
6. Increment `DX` if the search failed. Reset `CX`, `DI` and `SI`. Start from step 4 after decrementing `CX` by 1 (done by using the `LOOP` operation).

### Some outputs

[image: out]

There is an extra line in the third output because of the [following statements](https://gist.github.com/hjpotter92/6497303#file-prog-asm-L72) (line #72 & #73). The call to [`DISP_STR`](https://gist.github.com/hjpotter92/6497303#file-dispstr-asm) failed.

```
NEWLINE
CALL DISP_STR
```

## Code

#### PROG.ASM

```
TITLE Assignment: Read two strings and ...

.MODEL SMALL

    SAVE_REG MACRO REGS
        IRP D, <REGS>
            PUSH D
        ENDM
    ENDM
    LOAD_REG MACRO REGS
        IRP D, <REGS>
            POP D
        ENDM
    ENDM
    END_DOS MACRO
        MOV AH, 76
        INT 21H
    ENDM
    NEWLINE MACRO
        SAVE_REG <AX, DX>
        MOV AH, 2
        MOV DL, 0AH
        INT 21H
        MOV DL, 0DH
        INT 21H
        LOAD_REG <DX, AX>
    ENDM

.STACK 100H

.DATA

    STR1 DB 200 DUP(65)
    STR2 DB 200 DUP(0)
    PROMPT DB "Enter string "
    NUM DB "1: $"
    L1 DW 0
    UNEQL DB "No substring found$"
    EQUAL DB "Substring was found$"
.CODE

MAIN PROC

    MOV AX, @DATA
    MOV DS, AX
    MOV ES, AX
    MOV AH, 9
    LEA DX, PROMPT
    INT 21H
    LEA DI, STR1
    CALL READ_STR
    MOV L1, BX
    NEWLINE
    MOV NUM, '2'
    INT 21H
    CALL READ_STR
    LEA SI, STR1
    LEA DI, STR2        ; DI stores the longer string
    CMP L1, BX
      JE EQL
    CMP L1, BX
      JG INV
    MOV CX, BX
    SUB CX, L1
    JMP COMPARE
    INV:
    MOV CX, L1
    SUB CX, BX
    MOV L1, BX
    LEA SI, STR2
    LEA DI, STR1        ; DI stores longer string
    NEWLINE
    CALL DISP_STR
    JMP COMPARE
    EQL:
    MOV CX, 1
    COMPARE:
    XOR DX, DX
    TOP:
    SAVE_REG <DI, SI>
    ADD DI, DX
    PUSH CX
    MOV CX, L1
    REPE CMPSB
      JCXZ FOUND
    INC DX
    POP CX
    LOAD_REG <SI, DI>
    LOOP TOP
    NOT_FOUND:
    NEWLINE
    LEA DX, UNEQL
    MOV AH, 9
    INT 21H
    END_DOS
    FOUND:
    POP CX
    LOAD_REG <SI, DI>
    NEWLINE
    LEA DX, EQUAL
    MOV AH, 9
    INT 21H
    END_DOS

MAIN ENDP

    INCLUDE READSTR.ASM
    INCLUDE DISPSTR.ASM

END MAIN
```

#### DISPSTR.ASM

```
DISP_STR PROC

    SAVE_REG <AX, CX, DX, SI>
    MOV CX, BX
    CLD
    MOV AH, 2
    DISP_LOOP:
    LODSB
    MOV DL, AL
    INT 21H
    LOOP DISP_LOOP
    LOAD_REG <SI, DX, CX, AX>
    RET

DISP_STR ENDP
```

#### READSTR.ASM

```
READ_STR PROC

    SAVE_REG <AX, DI>
    XOR BX, BX
    CLD
    MOV AH, 1
    INT 21H
    WHILE_LOOP:
    CMP AL, 0DH
      JE END_WHILE
    CMP AL, 08H
      JNE STORAGE
    DEC BX
    DEC DI
    JMP NEXT
    STORAGE:
    STOSB
    INC BX
    NEXT:
    INT 21H
    JMP WHILE_LOOP
    END_WHILE:
    LOAD_REG <DI, AX>
    RET

READ_STR ENDP
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should learn to use a debugger so you can fix your code yourself.

Anyway, from a quick glance, the first obvious problem is that when you use `READ_STR` to read the second string you don't set up `DI` to point at `STR2`. As such, since `READ_STR` preserves `DI`, the second string will be read into `STR1` too, overwriting the first. Solution: move the `LEA DI, STR2` on [line 58](https://gist.github.com/hjpotter92/6497303#file-prog-asm-L58) up to before [line 56](https://gist.github.com/hjpotter92/6497303#file-prog-asm-L56). If there are no other errors lurking, that should fix it.

Comment: Yeah. That was the only error. Thanks a lot. Side note, can you link me to an easy tutorial about how to use debug provided with MASM version 5?

Answer (score 0):

To my mind , you can use this procedure :

You should take the shortest string and try to compare its first letter with all letters in the longest string and once the compare is true , move on to next letter in the shortest string and try to compare it with the next one in the longest string.

Some time ago, I coded a word unscrambler in MASM32 . the user provides a scrambled word figuring in the programs dictionary and the program unscrambles it and displays the right word.

In the way it works it might be a little bit helpful to you in your case when dealing with each letter alone.

Here's the code of the unscrambler I made :

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap:none
include /masm32/include/windows.inc
include /masm32/include/masm32.inc
include /masm32/include/kernel32.inc

includelib /masm32/lib/masm32.lib
includelib /masm32/lib/kernel32.lib

.data
not_found db "not_found",0
word0   db  "souhail",0
word1   db  "ability",0
word2  db"absence",0
word3 db "actions",0
word4  db "amazing",0 
word5  db "believe", 0
word6  db "browser", 0
word7  db "caption", 0
word8  db "captive", 0
word9  db "ceiling", 0
word10  db "degrees", 0
word11  db "denizen", 0
word12  db "develop", 0
word13  db "examine", 0
word14  db "example", 0
word15  db "exploit", 0
word16  db "fifteen", 0
word17  db "focused", 0
word18  db "fortune", 0
word19  db "forward",0
word20  db  "garbage", 0
word21  db  "gasping", 0
word22  db  "graphic", 0
word23  db  "handgun", 0
word24  db  "hastily", 0
word25  db  "helpful",0 
word26  db  "iceberg", 0
word27 db    "impeach", 0
word28 db    "inspect",0
word29 db    "jawbone", 0
word30 db     "justify", 0
word31 db     "keyword", 0
word32 db     "kickoff", 0
word33 db     "kneepad", 0
word34 db     "lactose", 0
word35 db     "latency", 0
word36 db     "legible", 0
word37 db     "madness", 0
word38 db     "magical", 0
word39 db     "manhunt", 0
word40 db     "mission", 0
word41 db     "nametag", 0
word42 db    "nitrate", 0
word43 db     "nowhere", 0
word44 db     "officer", 0
word45 db     "optical", 0
word46 db     "outlook", 0
word47 db     "oxidize", 0
word48 db     "paradox", 0
word49 db     "pathway", 0
word50 db     "patient", 0
word51 db     "payment", 0
word52 db     "qualify", 0
word53 db     "quality", 0
word54 db     "quarrel", 0
word55 db     "radical", 0
word56 db     "railing", 0
word57 db     "reduced", 0
word59 db     "resolve", 0
word60 db     "savings", 0
word61 db     "sayings", 0
word62 db     "scissor", 0
word63 db     "shadows", 0
word64 db     "tactics", 0
word65 db     "teacher", 0
word66 db     "terrify", 0
word67 db     "tractor", 0
word68 db     "unarmed", 0
word69 db     "unmasks", 0
word70 db     "updates", 0
word71 db     "vaccine", 0
word72 db     "valleys", 0
word73 db     "walnuts", 0
word74 db     "wealthy", 0
word75 db     "whacked", 0
word76 db     "willing", 0
word77 db     "wizards", 0
word78 db     "xysters", 0
word79 db     "yielded", 0
word80 db     "yoghurt", 0
word81 db     "younger",0
word82 db     "zippers" ,0
word83 db     "zombies",0
.data?
my_words db 1024 dup(?)
printme db  1024     dup(?)
exit        db  1024    dup(?)


.code
start :
First :
invoke StdIn, addr my_words, 200
lea eax, my_words
mov word ptr [eax+7],00
mov word ptr [eax+10h],00
lea edx, word1
push edx
mov esi,7                   ;set target word counter 
mov bl,byte ptr [eax]       ; mov first letter of input to bl

compare :
mov cl, byte ptr [edx]      ;mov letter of targer word to cl
cmp bl,cl
je add_one_to_my_word
inc edx
dec esi
cmp esi,0
je switch_to_next
jmp compare

add_one_to_my_word :
inc eax
mov bl,byte ptr [eax]
mov edx, dword ptr [esp] 
mov esi,7
cmp bl,0
je store1
jmp compare

switch_to_next :
lea eax,my_words
mov bl, byte ptr [eax]
pop edx
add edx,8
push edx
mov esi,7
cmp byte ptr [edx], 0
je notfound
jmp compare

store1 :
pop edx
lea eax, printme

store_12 :
mov bl, byte ptr [edx]
mov byte ptr [eax], bl
inc eax
inc edx
cmp byte ptr [edx], 0
jnz store_12

;invoke StdOut, addr printme
;invoke StdIn, addr exit, 200

Second :
lea eax, my_words
add eax,9
lea edx, word1
push edx
mov esi,7                   ;set target word counter 
mov bl,byte ptr [eax]       ; mov first letter of input to bl

compare2 :
mov cl, byte ptr [edx]      ;mov letter of targer word to cl
cmp bl,cl
je add_one_to_my_word_2
inc edx
dec esi
cmp esi,0
je switch_to_next_2
jmp compare2

add_one_to_my_word_2 :
inc eax
mov bl,byte ptr [eax]
mov edx, dword ptr [esp] 
mov esi,7
cmp bl,0
je store2
jmp compare2

switch_to_next_2 :
lea eax,my_words
add eax,9
mov bl, byte ptr [eax]
pop edx
add edx,8
push edx
mov esi,7
cmp byte ptr [edx], 0
je notfound
jmp compare2

store2 :
pop edx
lea eax, printme
add eax,8

store_22 :
mov bl, byte ptr [edx]
mov byte ptr [eax], bl
inc eax
inc edx
cmp byte ptr [edx], 0
jnz store_22

Third :
lea eax, my_words
add eax,12h
lea edx, word1
push edx
mov esi,7           ;set target word counter 
mov bl,byte ptr [eax]       ; mov first letter of input to bl

compare3 :
mov cl, byte ptr [edx]      ;mov letter of targer word to cl
cmp bl,cl
je add_one_to_my_word_3
inc edx
dec esi
cmp esi,0
je switch_to_next_3
jmp compare3

add_one_to_my_word_3 :
inc eax
mov bl,byte ptr [eax]
mov edx, dword ptr [esp] 
mov esi,7
cmp bl,0
je store3
jmp compare3

switch_to_next_3 :
lea eax,my_words
add eax,12h
mov bl, byte ptr [eax]
pop edx
add edx,8
push edx
mov esi,7
cmp byte ptr [edx], 0
je notfound
jmp compare3

store3 :
pop edx
lea eax, printme
add eax,11h

store_23 :
mov bl, byte ptr [edx]
mov byte ptr [eax], bl
inc eax
inc edx
cmp byte ptr [edx], 0
jnz store_23

Put_Order :
lea eax, printme
add eax,7
mov byte ptr [eax], 2Ch
add eax,8
mov word ptr [eax],202Ch
invoke StdOut, addr printme
invoke StdIn, addr exit, 200
call start
notfound :
invoke StdOut, addr not_found
invoke StdIn , addr exit,200


end start
```